# Unable to parse string to datastore.Key

Tags: go, datastore

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593806/making-a-google-app-engine-datastore-key-from-a-string), I am trying to convert a datastore key from the Form to int64 and with the help of that key, trying to update a record in the datastore. I tried exactly the same code as in the answer selected in the reference link, but I get an error  which says, `Unable to parse key. strconv.ParseInt: parsing "/Users,6248007768440574": invalid syntax`

The value I'm passing from the form is a datastore key of the format `/Users,6248007768440574`. I realize that the syntax error is because of this. Could anyone please help me in how to go about with this issue? Or, is there a method to convert a string to *datastore.Key? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ParseInt returns an error because the string `"/Users,6248007768440574"` is not an integer. A substring is an integer, but not the entire string.

The string in the question was created by calling [Key.String](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Key.String).  The datastore package does not provide a way to parse the output from this method. Here's a simple parser for the case where there are no ancestor keys:

```
var keyPat = regexp.MustCompile(`^/([^\.]*),(\d+)$`)

func parseKey(s string) (*datastore.Key, error) {
    m := keyPat.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    i := strings.Index(s, ",")
    if i < 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("bad format")
    }
    n, err := strconv.ParseInt(m[2], 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return datastore.IDKey(m[1], n, nil), nil
}
```

The the [Encode](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Key.Encode) method and [Decode](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#DecodeKey) function are the preferred way to convert a key to and from a machine readable string.

Comment: I get the following error - `    undefined: "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore".IDKey`

Comment: I'm importing "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore" and not  "cloud.google.com/go/datastore". how can i do the same with the former import.

Comment: To use the older google.golang.org/appengine/datastore  package, replace the call to IDKey with a call to [NewKey](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#NewKey).  As with the cloud.google.com/go/datastore package, the Encode method and Decode functions are the preferred way to get a key as a machine readable string.